# need a Column 'manager' containing unique managers and 'list_of_salesmen' containing an array of all salesmen under each manager

Tags: python, pandas

[Dataset Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xssuc.png)

So, with the dataset provided, as a beginner in python, I have created a dataframe as "SaleData" and written a code that displays me the result. However, is there any way using which I can remove the index?
or is there any better way I can find the result?

```
msdf = pd.DataFrame(SaleData[['Manager', 'SalesMan']]).sort_values(by= 'Manager')

msdf.reindex()

msdf.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do by removing the index? As far as I know you can't and shouldn't remove it.

Comment: as per your requirement: reset_index(drop, inplace=True)